# EF 5.0 and object inheritance mapping to same table by combining contexts

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5, dbcontext

I have a problem concerning EF 5.0 and the mapping of inherited objects to the same tables as the super class.

My project looks like this:

```
public class ContextA : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<EntityA> EntitiesA { get; set; }
    public DbSet<EntityB> EntitiesB { get; set; }

    public ContextA(string connnectionString) : base(connnectionString) { }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        ModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    public static void ModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<EntityA>().ToTable("EntityAs");
        modelBuilder.Entity<EntityB>().ToTable("EntityBs");

        modelBuilder.Entity<EntityA>().HasKey(e => e.EntityAId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<EntityB>().HasKey(e => e.EntityBId);
    }
}

public class EntityA
{
    public int EntityAId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class EntityB
{
    public int EntityBId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int EntityAId { get; set; }
}
```

So fine so good. Keep in mind, that the Entities A and B might be in a different schema of the database or could be in a different context which is the reason for the statc ModelCreation-method.

Now I want to combine the contexts like this:

```
public class ContextB : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<EntityAA> EntityAAs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<EntityBB> EntityBBs { get; set; }

    public ContextB(string connnectionString) : base(connnectionString) { }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        ModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    public static void ModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        ContextA.ModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<EntityAA>().Map(m =>
        {
            m.MapInheritedProperties();
            m.ToTable("EntityAs");
        }).HasKey(e => e.EntityAId)
        .Property(e => e.EntityAId)
        .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

        modelBuilder.Entity<EntityBB>().Map(m =>
        {
            m.MapInheritedProperties();
            m.ToTable("EntityBs");
        })
        .HasKey(e => e.EntityBId)
        .Property(e => e.EntityBId)
        .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

        modelBuilder.Entity<EntityAA>()
                    .HasMany(ea => ea.EntityBs)
                    .WithRequired(eb => eb.EntityA)
                    .HasForeignKey(eb => eb.EntityAId);
    }
}

public class EntityAA : EntityA
{
    private readonly List<EntityBB> _entityBbs = new List<EntityBB>();

    public virtual ICollection<EntityBB> EntityBs
    {
        get { return _entityBbs; }
    }
}

public class EntityBB : EntityB
{
    public EntityAA EntityA { get; set; }
}
```

I want to do this, because I want to have schema-specific contexts which I want to combine to a application-specific context in addition.

The problem is now, that I get an error during model creation:

```
Ergebnis Meldung:   Die EfInheritance.Test.GlobalTests.InsertEntitiesContextB-Testmethode hat eine Ausnahme ausgelöst: System.InvalidOperationException: The foreign key component 'EntityAId' is not a declared property on type 'EntityBB'. Verify that it has not been explicitly excluded from the model and that it is a valid primitive property.
Ergebnis StackTrace:    
bei System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Properties.Navigation.ForeignKeyConstraintConfiguration.Configure(EdmAssociationType associationType, EdmAssociationEnd dependentEnd, EntityTypeConfiguration entityTypeConfiguration)
   bei System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Properties.Navigation.NavigationPropertyConfiguration.ConfigureConstraint(EdmAssociationType associationType, EdmAssociationEnd dependentEnd, EntityTypeConfiguration entityTypeConfiguration)
   bei System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Properties.Navigation.NavigationPropertyConfiguration.ConfigureDependentBehavior(EdmAssociationType associationType, EdmModel model, EntityTypeConfiguration entityTypeConfiguration)
   bei System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Properties.Navigation.NavigationPropertyConfiguration.Configure(EdmNavigationProperty navigationProperty, EdmModel model, EntityTypeConfiguration entityTypeConfiguration)
   bei System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Types.EntityTypeConfiguration.ConfigureAssociations(EdmEntityType entityType, EdmModel model)
   bei System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Types.EntityTypeConfiguration.Configure(EdmEntityType entityType, EdmModel model)
   bei System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.ModelConfiguration.ConfigureEntities(EdmModel model)
   bei System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbProviderInfo providerInfo)
   bei System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection providerConnection)
   bei System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext internalContext)
   bei System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input)
   bei System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
   bei System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
   bei System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
   bei System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
   bei System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.ActOnSet(Action action, EntityState newState, Object entity, String methodName)
   bei System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Add(Object entity)
   bei System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.Add(TEntity entity)
   bei EfInheritance.Test.GlobalTests.InsertEntitiesContextB() in c:\temp\EfInheritance\EfInheritance.Test\GlobalTests.cs:Zeile 45.
```

In the end, my question is:

1. Is it possible to work like this at all?
2. If this is a possible solution, what could I do to get it to work?

If I comment the ForeignKey-Statement in ModelCreation, it works fine except the result in the database after running a simple test:

```
using (var ctx = new ContextB("CodeFirstDatabase"))
        {
            EntityAA aa = new EntityAA();
            aa.Name = "Test_AA_01";

            EntityBB bb = new EntityBB();
            bb.Name = "Test_BB_01";

            aa.EntityBs.Add(bb);

            ctx.EntityAAs.Add(aa);

            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
```

EntityBs
EntityBId | Name       | EntityAId | Discriminator | EntityA_EntityAId
1         | Test_BB_01 | 0         | EntityBB      | 1

EntityAs
EntityAId | Name       | Disciminator
1         | Test_AA_01 | EntityAA

Now there is an additional ForeignKeyColumn which I can't access as well as an additional discriminator-column.

Does someone have an idea what to do, to get this working? I have the project ready to mail/attach it if necessary.

Kind regards,

Sven

Comment: What is the end result you are trying to achieve?  This smacks of an XY problem, which is that you have come up with this as a solution to your problem, and you can't make it work, so you're asking how to solve this.  When in reality, you should be asking how to solve your original problem.

Comment: If you want to have multiple properties mapped to the same table you will always have additional discriminator column.

Comment: Edit: Multiple entities (not properties). What you are trying to do is called Table per hierarchy inheritance (TPH).

Comment: Hi, the basic idea was to have separate contexts per schema. To reduce maintenance we tried to combine these contexts for an application. For example: Imagine you have two database-schemas with data. First schema holds master-data which should be combined in more than one application and we want to separate them from the application specific schema. Is there another concept to achieve this?